# discord.py + PostgreSQL | 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, postgresql, discord, discord-api

Я пробовал писать по-разному этот ансамбль из букв, вроде как суть самой проблемы я понимаю, но я все не могу понять, как ее тут исправить.

Базы данных создаются, вроде как, без проблем, пользователи сервера туда заносятся, и запуск происходит успешно. Но при использовании команды `cash` выдает ту самую неприятную для меня ошибку

````
async def on_ready():

    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users( 
        name TEXT,
        id BIGINT NOT NULL,
        cash BIGINT,
        server_id BIGINT NOT NULL
    )""") # Создаем базу данных пользователей

    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop(
        role_id BIGINT,
        id BIGINT,
        cost BIGINT
    )""") # Создаем базу данных магазина

    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            cur.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}")
            row = cur.fetchone()
            if row is None: # Проверять пользователя на наличие в базе данных
                cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, {guild.id})") # Заносить пользователя в базу данных, если его нет
            else:
                pass # Пропустить пользователя
    con.commit()
    print("Активация прошла успешна") # Вывод в консоль готовности бота
    print('Подключение к базе данных прошло успешно')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    cur.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}")
    row= cur.fetchone()
    if row is None: # Проверять пользователя на наличие в базе данных
        cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, {member.guild.id})") # Заносить пользователя в базу данных, если его нет
        con.commit()
    else:
        pass # Пропустить пользователя

# Баланс | Cash | Balance
@client.command(aliases = ['cash', 'balance'])
async def __cash(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    query = cur.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)[0])
    result = cur.fetchone(query)
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{result}** :small_red_triangle_down:"""
        ))
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{member}** составляет **{result}** :small_red_triangle_down:"""
        ))

con.close()
client.run (settings['TOKEN']) # Запуск```
````

Comment: Проверьте, передается ли параметр member в функцию __cash. Потому как если он не будет передаваться, то и будет такая ошибка возникать.

Answer (score 0):

При создании команды вы добавили аргументу `member` стандартный параметр `None`, на тот случай, если при вызове команды `!cash` / `!balance` в чате дискорда, функции `__cash` не будет передан аргумент `member`.

Вы предусмотрели исключение этой ошибки при отправке результата, подставляя вместо `member` объект автора `ctx.author` на тот случай, если `member is None`, но забыли сделать это при выполнении запроса к базе данных.

Вам нужно точно также оформить запрос:

```
if member is None:
    query = cur.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)) 
else:
    query = cur.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id))
```